# Get event for incoming call when application in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

I am using CTCallCenter to fetch the call details. Now i need to fetch the details when application is running in background. I have implemented GPS functionality s that application can run in background and can listen the events for call notification but it seems not working.

Comment: are you developing VOIP app ?

Comment: if you are registering your app for "the GPS functionality" you will receive GPS related events, but not call events.

Comment: no i am not developing voip app.

Comment: Is there any way to get call event in background?

Comment: if you are not developing VOIP app, then you can't detect coming calls

Comment: I am able to detect call when application is in foreground

Comment: yes, if in foreground it is possible for all apps but when you are in the background it's hard. Check Background fetching for that, maybe you can do some checking when in background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTCallCenter - Call Event Handler - in background state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102108/ctcallcenter-call-event-handler-in-background-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i managed it. there was an issue with my background GPS tracking functionality implementation, i have correct it and my code works like charm. So confirming that we can track call when application is in background.

Comment: So, why your application uses GPS ? just for keep running app in background or something else?

Comment: No actually my application is also tracking user's location as well.

Comment: Hello @DipenPatel can I reach you offline, I have a requirement that you might be able to help with, please email me obi.onuorah[at] gmail dot com?