# CTCallCenter callEventHandler not executing the block in IOS9.0 & Xcode7

Tags: iphone, ios9

CTCallCenter callEventHandler not executing the block in IOS9.0  Xcode7
when the app is in background when we get call.

Comment: is it Apple IOS9 Bug? please provide your comment asap. Thank you

Comment: I opened a bug on Apple's bug report and a discussion : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16848.

To make the callback working, try to insert voip key in background modes : 

<code>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>voip</string>
    </array>
</code>

Comment: I have the same problem with iOS 9. As this is already a VOIP app, I can say with confidence that adding the VOIP background mode does not fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTCallCenter - Call Event Handler - in background state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102108/ctcallcenter-call-event-handler-in-background-state)