# CTCallCenter when app is not running

Tags: ios

iOS App:

I am working on the application which detect the incoming and outgoing call of the user. I am using the CTCallCenter to get the call events. App works properly for both Foreground and background mode for events.

My requirement is also to capture the call events when application is not running. Is there any way, app subscribes for call events and when any incoming or outgoing call is occurs it notifies my application? If not direct way there is any work-around available to achieve it?

Comment: Thank you Paul for quick reply. Can it be done if I add VOIP feature or Audio feature in my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTCallCenter - Call Event Handler - in background state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102108/ctcallcenter-call-event-handler-in-background-state)