# How can I get CTCallCenter Events in an iPhone Enterprise app in the background

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

I am looking for a way to get CTCallCenter Events on an enterprise app while it is in the background.  I came across the suggested solution by OhadM on this post: [How to get a call event using CTCallCenter:setCallEventHandler: that occurred while the app was suspended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195732/how-to-get-a-call-event-using-ctcallcentersetcalleventhandler-that-occurred-wh/35337831#35337831), but I can't get it to work with the app in the background.

I created a new single view app, added a callCenter property on the appDelegate and set the callEventHandler as shown in the post and listed below.  I also added the Voice over IP and Background fetch Background Modes Capabilities as described.

Is there any other settings or code not mentioned in the solution that may help?  I am using iOS 9.3.1 and Xcode 7.3.1.

```c
[self.callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call)
     {
         NSLog(@"Event handler called");
         if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
         {
             NSLog(@"Connected");
         }
         else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
         {
             NSLog(@"Dialing");
         }
         else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
         {
             NSLog(@"Disconnected");

         } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
         {
             NSLog(@"Incomming");
         }
     }];
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not.  And because I do not have 50 Stack Overflow points, I was not able to get clarification on OhadM's solution referenced above (which I could not get to work).  Maybe you can ask on that thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTCallCenter - Call Event Handler - in background state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102108/ctcallcenter-call-event-handler-in-background-state)